# HTTP status code for "No Content" message

Tags: http, http-status-codes

If server or site wants for visitors in certain countries show message

`There is no content available for your geographical location`,

what HTTP status code should be returned?

---

Regular `200` is too plain choice, code `204` does not allow to send response body; and `403` is Forbidden, which would be too strong and incorrect message.

The major point here is to return custom **NO CONTENT** message with correct HTTP code that should not be `200`, because in such case the response body is content and not an error message.

Comment: HTTP codes are supposed to be irrespective of the actual content (but can describe the content. e.g 206 for partial, 204 for none). 200 means the request could be processed and some content (as in any byte or character of data) could be served. For a webpage that is going to be interpreted by major browsers, 200 should be issued as there is **some** content being served (the error message the client sees counts). Besides, why does it matter anyway, I don't see much benefit gained from no sending a plain old 200.

Comment: @CPUTerminator - Problem here is that legally when server respond with status code `200`, response body is a content, so message "No Content" is a content, not an error message. Get it?

Comment: That is my point... Reiterating, what benefit do you gain from issuing a status code that is **not** `200`?

Comment: @CPUTerminator - So I need such response body to be an error message and therefore response code has to be an error code, not `200 OK`

Comment: @CPUTerminator - Some response codes are error codes. Code `200` is not an error code...

Comment: Sounds like 404 Not Found is what you are looking for. Unless you are determining geo by geo-ip. Which I can't really advise on since its not very RESTful.

Comment: Once again, HTTP status codes indicate the type of response, or if any errors were encountered. A "error" with the fact that the user is in an area where "site"-content cannot be served is **not** a HTTP error, as the nature of the error is **not** of the protocol. You'll notice status codes like 204 belong in the 2xx family which represent **success** and not error.

Comment: To determinate if content is shown or the error message is shown, `.htaccess` redirection based on geo-IP information is used...

Comment: @CPUTerminator - I don't agree that status codes are just about protocol. Some of them yes, but not all...

Comment: @Aron - I was also thinking about `404`, as it seems to be the only option, but it should be used when server has not found anything matching the URI given...

Comment: RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1) Section 10.2.1: Status: 200 OK -  The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the response (I assumed you respond to a GET request). Based on my understanding of your question, your HTTP response confines to that description perfectly. Your server has successfully generated a response that confines to the user's request, whether this response be "a no context" message or not.

Comment: @CPUTerminator - I hear you, but due to legal issues a wording "no content is available" is required to be used and we need to ensure that such message is not a content. It is hard, I know... :(

Comment: Well, if its so essential that a "correct" response be issued that fits your nature of your response, I'm afraid there isn't one that suits it best without breaking some tiny rule somewhere (either legally, or the HTTP specification). Personally, I would send a `200` but I recommend you to propose this to the IETF and perhaps set up a whole new response code. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to show an error message to the end users and not for programs (computers), then I think you don't have any other options just to use `200`.

If you want to respond to programs then changing the [reason-phrase](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) sounds like the proper way to go.

```
GET /non-existing-location HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost

HTTP/1.1 204 There is no content available for your geographical location
Date: Sun, 10 Nov 2013 16:23:32 GMT
```

Comment: I believe with response code `204` browser (client) shows no message, does not change current view/page and does not even add such request to a browse history...

Comment: That's why I wrote if you want to say anything to your users you should stick with `200`.